# Problem with Ogmo Editor (is Tiled Editor a solution?)

Tags: tiles, tools, level-design, map-editor

I made a level editor for a puzzle game with [Ogmo Editor](http://www.ogmoeditor.com/) and gave it to our designer/level designer. When he downloaded and started Ogmo, his CPU went to 100%. I looked at my CPU usage while Ogmo is running, and it goes from 20% to 30% (which is also high for an application alike Ogmo). He has a Windows 7 VM running on his Mac and I have a normal Windows PC, can this be a problem?

I found a [thread on FlashFunk forum](http://flashpunk.net/forums/index.php?topic=4687.0) that confirms that Ogmo has CPU usage issues. Has anybody maybe solved this issue?

The solution seems to use [Tiled Editor](http://www.mapeditor.org/), but I never used it before. Is it difficult to change a level editor from Ogmo to Tiled? Can they export in the same format (XML with CSV elements for my puzzle game)?

**EDIT**

I ended up re-making the level editor with Tiled. It wasn't difficult and the only problem was that the exported XML is slightly different. In Ogmo the layers names are exported as XML element names, and in Tiled all layers are exported as  elements with the layer name as the name attribute of the layer element.

My first question still remains: has anybody managed to solve the high CPU usage of the new version of Ogmo?

Comment: The format used by Tiled is also based on XML however, there is no native way to import a Ogmo formatted map within Tiled. Maybe tools exist on the internet that would do the conversion (or you can do it yourself).

Answer (score 1):

20-30% is plenty normal. It's far from being too CPU dependent. 
You also have to remember that the numbers inside taskmanager not only represent a single application but your whole system. So Ogmo alone might not be what is using 20-30% of your CPU's overall performance capacity.

As for your level designer's performance issues. He's running the application from within a simulated/virtual environment, so it's pretty obvious that he would take a major. performance hit.

Comment: 20-30% was the CPU usage for only the Ogmo editor process, not the whole CPU. Firefox sometimes uses more than that, but I thought it strange for a "lightweight" application like Ogmo...